# Listen to http request on webpage

Tags: javascript, http

I'm now creating a script on my website, which will need a bi-direction connection (the script is a chat room window). But we don't want to create a socket. Instead, we want to make client(the script) and server both have ability of sending http request to each other. 
(BTW, the website server and script server are two different servers)
It is very easy for client(the script) to send http request to our server. But it is a big problem for the client(the script) to listen to http requests.
I have done some search but found nothing, maybe this requirement is so weird that seldom been used? Is it possible for a script which embeded in webpage that listen for http request?

Thanks!

Comment: Use [WebSockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) and keep a persistant connection open.

Comment: if you dont want socket, try this http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/

Comment: Great! That's almost what I am finding! But seems like IE/edge does not support that!?

Comment: What's the reason you don't want to create a socket?

Comment: That's a bit complicated. If I can, I would choose to use socket create connection. But I need a back up plan if my teammate cannot create a server which capable of creating socket.

Comment: Even with SSEs, you need something very similar to a socket-handling server. Specifically the way the server will need internal signalling to know when to send what to whom. If you can get that far, it's just a tiny step further to a full socket connection, which would then in fact simplify your implementation, because you have one socket to send messages over instead of a REST/unidirectional-socket hybrid.

Answer (score 4):

In order to receive an HTTP request, you must:

1. have a publicly accessible IP address
2. have an open port, publicly accessible
3. bind a program to that port to listen for HTTP requests

Browsers fall down on all three counts. You cannot expect that all of your clients have a publicly reachable, unblocked IP address with specifically the port open that you want. But even if that were the case, there's no way for the browser to listen to incoming requests; there's no API to do that in the browser, partly because the browser is an HTTP *client* and not a server, partly because offering such an API would probably provide an extremely powerful API to all sorts of attackers, and partly because it oftentimes is useless anyway because the browser cannot be reached anyway (see point 1).

So, no, you cannot turn the browser into an HTTP server.

Use WebSockets.

Comment: Seems like although I can't directly receive HTTP request from server, I can send server an HTTP request first and make the server use 'Server-Sent Events'(@JAG 's suggestion in comment) to start sending data.

Comment: Which is essentially the same thing a WebSocket does, just unidirectional and therefore more limited. The browser opens a connection to the server, and both keep the connection open.

Comment: @deceze would it be possible to have the browser listen for webSocket connections from localhost? I know I can, and have, connected to my C# websocket server running on local host from the browser, but in this instance I need the browser act as the 'server' and listen for connection requests from 127.0.0.1. (either pure ws:// or as http:// that's then upgraded to ws://)

Comment: @Reahreic The browser has no address or port to which you could send a request or connect. No, the browser cannot act as a server.